# assigning a numeric value inside an object literal is not throwing any error

Tags: javascript, node.js

consider the following code:

```js
let logged = 1;
let x = {logged} //{logged: 1} 
x['logged']; // 1
x['logged']['index']; //undefined
x['logged']['index'] = 0; 
x; // {logged: 1}
x['logged']['index']; //undefined
```

So, my questions are:
isn't

- `x[logged]['index']` doing something like `1['index']`. Shouldn't
  which give something like `cannot index a numeric literal` kind of
  error?
- `x[logged]['index'] = 0;`, this doesn't throw any error, as if the
  element is stored somewhere, but, where is this value being stored?
  As shown in `line 6`, the value of x is still `{logged: 1}`. And why does it not throw error?
  and why is x[logged]['index'] is still undefined?

*I tested this on a nodejs terminal, with node version 14.16.0*

Comment: This is because of primitive object wrappers. Essentially anytime you try to use a primlitive in an object context, javascript tries to box the primitive to its wrapper object.

Comment: if you're familiar with it, could you please explain it with context to my questions?

Comment: because `1` isn't an object, specifically you can't add attributes to a number

Comment: When you write 1['index'] or '1'['index'], you indicate that you want to index something. As you point out, it is not possible to index a primitive value, so javascript resolves this by boxing the number/string to new Number(1)/String('1') and indexing that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my comments above actually fully illuminated the issue for you.

I have written a small program that may be helpfull to visualize what happens. Note I'm doing a method lookup on a primitive value rather than a regular property lookup - but this is all just the same and allows to illustrate what happens better.

```
function captureThis() {
    return this
}
(function setUpObjectPrototype() {
    if (Object.prototype.captureThis !== undefined) throw new Error("Couldn't set up Object prototype properly.")
    Object.prototype.captureThis = captureThis
    process.nextTick(() => delete Object.prototype.captureThis)
})()

var number = 1
var thisObject = number.captureThis()

console.log("Is thisObject an object? " + (typeof thisObject == "object"))
console.log("Is number still just a number? " + (typeof number == "number"))
console.log("Is thisObject an instance of Number? " + (thisObject instanceof Number))

// Output
// Is thisObject an object? true
// Is number still just a number? true
// Is thisObject an instance of Number? true
```

Note that at no point is the number variable actually coerced to an object - a temporary object is created that wraps the value contained in the number variable. This object is never actually assigned to a variable - unless it is captured like it is in this little program.

Hopefully that helps.